# Error in deleting the user account with FirebaseUI Auth. Service

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working in a project with FirebaseUI and I want to give the user ability to delete his account. I've used this code from Firebase Documentation:

```
    @IBAction func deleteTheAccountButtonHasBeenTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
    
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

    user?.delete { error in
      if let error = error {
        print(error)
      } else {
        self.defaults.set(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let LoginVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! LoginVC
        self.present(LoginVC, animated:true, completion:nil)
      }
    }
    
}
```

unfortunately I keep getting the error:

> Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17014 "This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request., FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_REQUIRES_RECENT_LOGIN}

it requires to re-authenticate the current user, anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature of Firebase. Some actions require recent login of the user to verify the authencity of the request, so you would need to read the error code and reauthenticate the user accordingly. You can read the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors#deletewithcompletion)

Comment: I use FirebaseUI for authentication, can you help me here?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63860795/how-to-sign-out-and-delete-users-register-by-firebaseui-swift-5