# How to Sign out and Delete Users Register By FirebaseUI Swift 5

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I want to give my app the ability to Log out/delete the user and when I type this code

```
    @IBAction func deleteTheAccountButtonHasBeenTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    var credential: AuthCredential
    
    user?.reauthenticateAndRetrieveData(with: credential, completion: {(authResult, error) in
        if let error = error {
            // An error happened.
            print(error)
        }else{
            //user re-authenticated
            user?.delete { error in
              if let error = error {
                // An error happened.
                print(error)
              } else {
                // Account deleted.
                let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! LoginVC
                self.present(vc, animated:true, completion:nil)
              }
            }
            
        }
    })
}
```

I got this error:

> Variable 'credential' used before being initialized

any one can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty explicit: you're using `credential` before you initialized it.

In order to delete the user, you need to first reauthenticate them, as shown in the documentation on [reauthenticating the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user). Your version doesn't implement this comment from that code:

```
// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
```

How to reauthenticate the user depends on the provider. For example for email/password, you'd get them with:

```
credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)
```

A handy place to find similar snippets for other providers is in the documentation on [linking accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking#link-auth-provider-credentials-to-a-user-account).

Comment: I've set two auth providers [Apple,Google] how should I write the credential in this case?

Comment: If I remember correctly reauthenticating with either of them should be enough. So pick (or let the user pick) one provider from the page I linked, and create credentials for that.